# find where the interrupt happened on cortex-m4

Tags: gdb, arm, cortex-m

I am trying to find where in my code a specific interrupt happened. In this case it is on a stm32f4 microcontroller and the interrupt is the SysTick_Handler.

What i want is basically to figure out from where the systick interrupt happened. I am using arm-none-eabi-gdb to try to find the backtrace, but the only information i am getting from there is:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  SysTick_Handler () at modules/profiling.c:66
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x55555554 in ?? () Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

How can I get some information about where the program was before the interrupt fired?

Looking at the arm documentation [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/Babefdjc.html), it seems I should be able to read the stack pointer, and get the PC from there. But then this is exactly what the unwinder in GDB is doing isnt it?

Comment: Was the interrupted code running with the main stack? If it was running with the process stack, then you're unwinding the wrong one (since Handler mode always uses MSP). As per the docs you linked, the relevant stack is encoded in the EXC_RETURN value.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I now have a code in my SysTick_Handler that actually reads out the correct PC from where i was last time. Still, its to bad that GDB doesnt unwind correctly.

Comment: You can write `gdb` macros to do this.  MSP is cortex-m specific and GDB is written to run on many different platforms and is mainly concerned with user applications.  That said, it is open source and I am sure contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many of you commented, the PC would be in two different stacks, the way I solved it was by actually finding a HardFault_Handling code in assembly and taking what i needed from there. To get the PC value correctly I am using the following code.

```
register int *r0 __asm("r0");

__asm(  "TST lr, #4\n"
        "ITE EQ\n"
        "MRSEQ r0, MSP\n"
        "MRSNE r0, PSP\n" // stack pointer now in r0
        "ldr r0, [r0, #0x18]\n" // stored pc now in r0
        //"add r0, r0, #6\n" // address to stored pc now in r0
     );
```

The value of where the interrupt happended can now be accessed by

```
uint32_t PC = *r0;
```

and can now be used for whatever I want it. Unfortunately I did not manage to get GDB to unwind the stack automatically for me. But at least I found out where the interrupt was firing, which was the goal.

Answer (score 5):

You were on the right track at the end of your question. The ARM Cortex-M cores have two stack pointers, the main stack pointer (MSP, used for interrupts) and the process stack pointer (PSP, used for tasks).

When an interrupt with priority comes in, the current register values (for most of the registers) are pushed onto the current stack (PSP if interrupting the background application, or MSP if interrupting a lower priority interrupt), and then the stack is switched to the MSP (if not already there).

When you first enter an interrupt, the link register (LR, return address) will have a value that is mostly F's rather than an actual return address. This value tells the core how to exit when branched to. Typically, you'll see a value of `0xFFFFFFFD` if the background task was interrupted, or `0xFFFFFFF1` if a lower priority interrupt was interrupted. These values will differ if you are using the floating point unit. The magic in this value, though, is that bit 2 (`0x4`) tells you whether your stack frame is on the PSP or MSP.

Once you determine which stack your frame is on, you can find the address you were executing from by looking at the appropriate stack pointer minus 24 (6 32-bit locations). See Figure 2.3 in your link. This will point you to the PC from which you were interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

We keep seeing this question in various forms and folks keep saying there are two stacks.  So I tried it myself with the systick.

The documentation says that we are in thread mode out of reset, and if you halt with openocd it says that

```
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
```

I have some code to dump registers:

```
20000000 APSR
00000000 IPSR
00000000 EPSR
00000000 CONTROL
00000000 SP_PROCESS
20000D00 SP_PROCESS after I modified it
20000FF0 SP_MAIN
20000FF0 mov r0,sp  
then I dump the stack up to 0x20001000 which is where I know my stack started
20000FF0 00000000 
20000FF4 00000000 
20000FF8 00000000 
20000FFC 0100005F
```

I setup and wait for a systick interrupt, the handler dumps registers and ram and then goes into an infinite loop.  bad practice in general but just debugging/learning here.  Before the interrupt I prep some registers:

```
.thumb_func
.globl iwait
iwait:
    mov r0,#1
    mov r1,#2
    mov r2,#3
    mov r3,#4
    mov r4,#13
    mov r12,r4
    mov r4,#15
    mov r14,r4
    b .
```

and in the handler I see

```
20000000 APSR
0000000F IPSR
00000000 EPSR
00000000 CONTROL
20000D00 SP_PROCESS
20000FC0 SP_MAIN
20000FC0 mov r0,sp
20000FC0 0000000F 
20000FC4 20000FFF 
20000FC8 00000000 
20000FCC FFFFFFF9  this is our special lr (not one rjp mentioned)
20000FD0 00000001  this is r0
20000FD4 00000002  this is r1
20000FD8 00000003  this is r2
20000FDC 00000004  this is r3
20000FE0 0000000D  this is r12
20000FE4 0000000F  this is r14/lr
20000FE8 01000074  and this is where we were interrupted from
20000FEC 21000000  this is probably the xpsr mentioned
20000FF0 00000000  stuff that was there before
20000FF4 00000000 
20000FF8 00000000 
20000FFC 0100005F 


01000064 <iwait>:
 1000064:   2001        movs    r0, #1
 1000066:   2102        movs    r1, #2
 1000068:   2203        movs    r2, #3
 100006a:   2304        movs    r3, #4
 100006c:   240d        movs    r4, #13
 100006e:   46a4        mov ip, r4
 1000070:   240f        movs    r4, #15
 1000072:   46a6        mov lr, r4
 1000074:   e7fe        b.n 1000074 <iwait+0x10>
 1000076:   bf00        nop
```

So in this case, straight out of the ARM documentation, it is not using the sp_process it is using sp_main.  It is pushing the items the manual says it is pushing including the interrupted/return address which is 0x1000074.

Now, if I set the SPSEL bit (be careful to set the PSP first), it appears that a mov r0,sp in application/thread mode uses the PSP not MSP.  But then the handler uses msp for a mov r0,sp  but appears to put the

before in thread/foreground

```
20000000 APSR
00000000 IPSR
00000000 EPSR
00000000 SP_PROCESS
20000D00 SP_PROCESS modified
00000000 CONTROL
00000002 CONTROL modified
20000FF0 SP_MAIN
20000D00 mov r0,sp
```

now in the handler

```
20000000 APSR
0000000F IPSR
00000000 EPSR
00000000 CONTROL (interesting!)
20000CE0 SP_PROCESS
20000FE0 SP_MAIN
20000FE0 mov r0,sp
dump of that stack
20000FE0 0000000F 
20000FE4 20000CFF 
20000FE8 00000000 
20000FEC FFFFFFFD 
20000FF0 00000000 
20000FF4 00000000 
20000FF8 00000000 
20000FFC 0100005F 
dump of sp_process stack
20000CE0 00000001 
20000CE4 00000002 
20000CE8 00000003 
20000CEC 00000004 
20000CF0 0000000D 
20000CF4 0000000F 
20000CF8 01000074 our return value
20000CFC 21000000
```

So to be in this position of dealing with the alternate stack that folks keep mentioning, you have to put yourself in that position (or some code you rely on).  Why you would want to do that for simple bare metal programs, who knows, the control register of all zeros is nice and easy, can share one stack just fine.

I dont use gdb, but you need to get it to dump all the registers sp_process and sp_main then depending on what you find, then dump a dozen or so words at each and in there you should see the 0xFFFFFFFx as a marker then count down from that to see the return address.  You can have your handler read the two stack pointers as well then you can look at gprs.  With gnu assembler mrs rX,psp; mrs rX,msp;  For the process and main stack pointers.

Comment: note this is a cortex-m4 in a ti msp432 launchpad.  I have others but this was good enough to demonstrate that you may not necessarily be dealing with the dual stack thing, esp if you didnt set up the alternate stack.

Answer (score -6):

This is called DEBUGGING.  The easiest way to get started is to just stick a bunch of printf() calls here and there throughout the code.  Run the program.  If it prints out:

got to point A
got to point B
got to point C

and dies, then you know it died between "C" and "D."  You can now refine that downwards by festooning the code between "C" and "D" with more closely spaced printf() calls.

This is the best way for a beginner to get started.  Many seasoned experts also prefer printf() for debugging.  Debuggers can get in the way.

Comment: This does not help me, since my program isnt crashing, 
I do not have printf, and i specifically want to know where the interrupt happened from